# Draw and move a shape (rectangle) while there is an active selection (PS-CC)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I'm doing image analysis of microscopy images. I often make a selection with the selection tool to grab parts of images. Then, inside of the selection area, I need to move shapes (such as lines and rectangles). The problem is, I can't seem to move in the shapes without also moving the active selection. Is there a way to be able to move a rectangle or line without also moving my selection? Right now I usually save and then reload the selection, but there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is *not*.

With an active selection, Photoshop assumes it is *that* area to be altered. There's no inherent method which tells Photoshop to create a selection (active area) but then *not* alter that active area. In fact, that is the entire logic behind selections. Saving and then reloading selection is really the only method if you must use selections.

You could use shape layers and then move anything as needed *without* selections at all. However, I have no clue what your images look like or if using shape layers is even possible for your work.

You may also be able to better utilize layer masks. But again.. no clue what your images look like or what *specifically* you are doing. Layer masks could be wildly inappropriate.